# Change style of the right icon error TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout, material-components, material-components-android

I want to change the style of the right icon error (the image with ! sign) in a `TextInputLayout` but I don't find how.

It is possible?.

[image: TextInputLayout]

Comment: Could you provide the code you are using now.Looks like you are setting error on edittext.

Answer (score 2):

With the Material Component Library just use the **`app:errorIconDrawable`** attribute.

Something like:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    app:errorIconDrawable="@drawable/..."
    ../>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To do this in your Java class, you can do something like this:

```
// initialize your drawable object
Drawable myErrorDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_error_drawable);

// set the dimension/bounds
myErrorDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, myErrorDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), myErrorDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight());

// attach the drawable to your EditText.
editText.setError("An error occured", myErrorDrawable);
```